# Swift dismiss/unwind to modals not working in xcode 6 beta 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been trying to dismiss a modal using Storyboards but from reading an old beta release it seems those are broken.  I tried adding the header to allow me to do unwind from the Obj-C side but still nothing.

this is in my swift file

```
@objc(BeersViewController) class BeersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBAction func unwindToBeersMainViewController(sender:UIStoryboardSegue) {
   println("hello world");
  }

}
```

this is in my header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface BeersViewController

- (IBAction)unwindToBeersMainViewController: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

@end
```

I then in storyboard dragged from the button to exit.  When I try to run it in the simulator it just does nothing.

Any other ideas?  I copied this from another thread on here but didn't seem to work past getting it to show up from exposing Obj-C to swift

Comment: I have a similar issue with Objective-C in xcode6.

Comment: It's Xcode 6 beta 3 bug. If you switch simulator to 7.1, unwind segues will work, but then images break..

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6 Beta 4 this bug has been resolved. I had the same problem in one of my projects. After the upgrade everything worked fine :-)